# Use bcc SKB to drop TCP packet

Tags: c++, ebpf, bpf

Intention: To drop tcp/port packet using bcc tools

I stumbled upon this code

```
int drop(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    const int l3_off = ETH_HLEN;                       // IP header offset
    const int l4_off = l3_off + sizeof(struct iphdr);  // TCP header offset
    const int l7_off = l4_off + sizeof(struct tcphdr); // L7 (e.g. HTTP) header offset

    void *data = (void*)(long)skb->data;
    void *data_end = (void*)(long)skb->data_end;

    if (data_end < data + l7_off)
        return TC_ACT_OK; // Not our packet, handover to kernel

    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    if (eth->h_proto != htons(ETH_P_IP))
       return TC_ACT_OK; // Not an IPv4 packet, handover to kernel

    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *)(data + l3_off);
    if (ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *)(data + l4_off);
    if (ntohs(tcp->dest) != 80)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    return TC_ACT_SHOT;
}
```

I tried implementing this in bcc, but it spited out error as permission denied. Any examples I can look at for tcp/port level blocking.

This was my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import time
import atexit
import argparse

from bcc import BPF, BPFAttachType, lib


examples = """examples:
    ./sockmap.py -c /root/cgroup # attach to /root/cgroup
"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="pipe data across multiple sockets",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        epilog=examples)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--cgroup", required=True,
        help="Specify the cgroup address. Note. must be cgroup2")

bpf_text = '''
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

#define MAX_SOCK_OPS_MAP_ENTRIES 65535
struct sock_key {
    u32 remote_ip4;
    u32 local_ip4;
    u32 remote_port;
    u32 local_port;
    u32 family;
};
BPF_SOCKHASH(sock_hash, struct sock_key, MAX_SOCK_OPS_MAP_ENTRIES);
.
.
.
int drop(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    const int l3_off = ETH_HLEN;                       // IP header offset
    const int l4_off = l3_off + sizeof(struct iphdr);  // TCP header offset
    const int l7_off = l4_off + sizeof(struct tcphdr); // L7 (e.g. HTTP) header offset

    void *data = (void*)(long)skb->data;
    void *data_end = (void*)(long)skb->data_end;

    if (data_end < data + l7_off)
        return TC_ACT_OK; // Not our packet, handover to kernel

    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    if (eth->h_proto != htons(ETH_P_IP))
       return TC_ACT_OK; // Not an IPv4 packet, handover to kernel

    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *)(data + l3_off);
    if (ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *)(data + l4_off);
    if (ntohs(tcp->dest) != 80)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    return TC_ACT_SHOT;
}
'''
args = parser.parse_args()
bpf = BPF(text=bpf_text)
func_sock_ops = bpf.load_func("drop", bpf.SOCK_OPS)
func_sock_redir = bpf.load_func("bpf_redir", bpf.SK_MSG)

# raise if error
fd = os.open(args.cgroup, os.O_RDONLY)
map_fd = lib.bpf_table_fd(bpf.module, b"sock_hash")
bpf.attach_func(func_sock_ops, fd, BPFAttachType.CGROUP_SOCK_OPS)
bpf.attach_func(func_sock_redir, map_fd, BPFAttachType.SK_MSG_VERDICT)

def detach_all():
    bpf.detach_func(func_sock_ops, fd, BPFAttachType.CGROUP_SOCK_OPS)
    bpf.detach_func(func_sock_redir, map_fd, BPFAttachType.SK_MSG_VERDICT)
    print("Detaching...")

atexit.register(detach_all)

while True:
    try:
        bpf.trace_print()
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Skipping the extra code, code template was injested from bcc/examples/networking/sockmap.py

Answer (score 1):

The program you want to use is a TC eBPF program, but you are trying to attach it to a cGroup. I recommend taking [tc_perf_event.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/2731825b9327a9a720f2ef92ed891ce0525a8dc3/examples/networking/tc_perf_event.py) as a base and modifying it by replacing the eBPF program with your block program. (and removing the perf part of the example).